# Pentaho Dashboard Performance

Tags: bigdata, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I have a CDE dashboard developed with Pentaho CE 6.0.1 with 4 line charts. My plugins are updated.

Our dataset is a SQL Server database with millions of records (near to 80 millions).

The BA Server is running in a cloud enviroment as the database as well and queries in database motor run at very few seconds.

The dashboard performance is very poor, it takes almost 2 minutes to full load. I tried to remove 3 of the charts and leave only the principal but the load times didn't change at all.

Do you think I need a big data approach for this amount of data?

Can you please help me providing me some performance tuning tips in order to improve this behavior?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Can you post here the chrome devtool network tab screen shot for that dashboard

Comment: @Gaj added print in a answer below. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

with sql server you will face this problem, workarounds are you can increase the ram , you can enable catch so for the first time it will take time after that it will be smooth but again no concrete solution.
Either you have to change to columnar database like HP vertica or you can do changes at architecture level, create data-warehouse and store only necessary data

Comment: Do you think is any workaround I can do in the Apache Tomcat Server or in the database itself? Pentaho has 10 GB of RAM currently. Thanks a lot!

Comment: as i mention,you have to do changes in design(datawarehouse) of architecture based on your project.